# Change X and Y Axes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I am trying to graph the temperature of a substance versus the time the substance has been heated. My data is:

```
      A         |        B
Time (Minutes)  | Temperature (ºC)
0               | 22.8
.5              | 24.5
1               | 32.2
1.5             | 37.8
```

When I select the two columns and choose ***Insert -> Graph***, it puts both of them on the same axis.

**"Use column B as labels"** is an option but I want to use column A.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This could be because one your columns is formatted as plain text, not as numbers. This restricts the roles of axes, as text values are automatically assumed to be labels.

Using the input from your example, with both columns formatted as numbers, I have no problem using Column A as labels:

[image: chart]

Answer (score -1):

switch the values and then the option "use column B as labels" will be right.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. You would need to elaborate on this for it to be a good answer. It is also useful to set up an example spreadsheet and link to it from your answer.